# SimpleXmlElement failes to fetch items

Tags: php, mysql, function, rss, simplexml

I have made a function like this:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    echo "<h3>".$x->channel->title."</h3><div>";
    foreach ($x->channel->item as $entry) {

        $title = utf8_decode(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($entry->title)));
        $link = utf8_decode(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($entry->link)));
        $desc = utf8_decode(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($entry->description)));
        $chkexist="SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title='$title' LIMIT 1";
        $i =1;


        $chkresult=mysql_query($chkexist);
        $countresult=mysql_num_rows($chkresult);
        if ($title=="") {
            echo "No article title, skipping ".$i++."<br>";
        }else{
            if ($countresult==1) {
            echo "The article: ".utf8_encode($title)." Exists. Passing.<br>";
            }else {
                $sql="INSERT INTO articles (title,link,description,date) VALUES ('$title','$link','$desc',NOW())";
                mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed to save articles");
                echo "The article: ".utf8_encode($title)." Is saved<br>";
            }
        }   
    }
echo "</div>";
}
```

It is probably no perfect, im pretty new to this game, but when i try to give it for example this feed: http://www.tek.no/feeds/general.xml it ends up saving but not all items and it gives an error at the end saying: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 29 Failed to save articles.

As you can see im working local.

If i try another feed like: http://www.dagbladet.no/rss/innenriks/ it saves 4 items and gives just the custom error message in the query, not Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter.. etc.

Any idea what i am doing wrong here? Does anyone have xampp or wampp to try out the function?

Comment: obviously, your query `$chkresult` doesn't return records from the db. do a `var_dump($chkexist);` after `$i=1;`

Comment: Its not that obvoius if you dont have the programming skills to understand the function. Thanks for the help, ill try that and look what happends, i need to learn how to debug/diagnose my code :-) Thanks again.

Comment: Solved it with another if statement that checks that $chkresult have a value.

Comment: Actually, the $desc did not get escaped, and i sent the variable throug `mysql_real_escape_string();` So in my query i did this: 

`$sql="INSERT INTO articles (title,link,description,pubdate,date) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($link)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($desc)."','$pubdate',NOW())";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the $desc did not get escaped, and i sent the variable throug mysql_real_escape_string(); So in my query i did this: $sql="INSERT INTO articles (title,link,description,pubdate,date) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($link)."','"‌​.mysql_real_escape_string($desc)."','$pubdate',NOW())";

Now it works.